Once $X\sim \text{gamma}(\alpha = 12, \beta = 2)$ is observed, $Y$ is randomly chosen from $(0,x)$. Evaluate $E(Y)$

Random variable $X\sim \text{gamma}(\alpha = 12, \beta = 2)$. Once $X=x\gt 0$ is observed, $Y$ is randomly chosen from $(0,x)$. Evaluate $E(Y)$.

Well I know $E(Y)=E_X[E(Y|X)]$ so I'll proceed by finding
$$E(Y|X)=\int_{\infty}^{\infty}yg_2(y|x)dy$$
I think $$g_2(y|x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_1(x)}$$
I don't know how to find $f(x,y)$ or $f_1(x)$. Is $f_1(x)$ simply the gamma distribution (where $x\gt 0$)?:
$$f_1(x|12,2)=\frac{2^{12}}{\Gamma(12)}x^{\alpha -1}e^{-\beta x}$$ I'm quite lost on what to do.

Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Think about it this way: If I sampled $X$ and told you its value, say $X = 9$, what would you say is the expected value $E(Y|X = 9)$?

From 'randomly chosen from $(0,x)$' we infer that, given any fixed value $x$ that $X$ can take, $Y$ follows a uniform distribution in $(0,x)$.
This means that $E[Y\,|\,X=x]=\dfrac{x}{2}$, and so $E[Y\,|\,X]=\dfrac{X}{2}$ as random variables.
Thus, $E[Y]=E[E[Y\,|\,X]]=\dfrac{E[X]}{2}$.
As $X\sim G(12,2)$ we have $E[X]=\dfrac{12}{2}=6$ and so $E[Y]=3$.

That was a lot simpler than I thought, thank you
